# Bind command show_at_center to space bar in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, key-bindings

In vim, in command mode, I'm quite fond of using the space bar to center the current line on screen. `nmap <space> zz` maps this functionality to the space bar in my gvimrc file. I'm trying to bind the same functionality to the space bar in Sublime Text 2:

```
{ "keys": ["space"], "command": "show_at_center", "args": {"command_mode": true} }
```

The line above doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why, and what will? I have Sublime's Vintage mode enabled. Also, I have `“scroll_past_end”: true` in my Sublime Text 2 User Preference Settings so that even the last lines of a file can be centered.

Comment: where do you have this keybinding defined?

Comment: I've defined it in `Packages/User/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap`, through the menu items `Sublime Text 2->Preferences->Key Bindings - User`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to `Packages/User/Vintage/Default (<your OS>).sublime-keymap`:

```json
{ "keys": ["space"], "command": "show_at_center",
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.command_mode"}
    ]
}
```

I can't test it right now, but it *should* work :)

**EDIT** - it doesn't. See below...

---

### ***UPDATE***

So I've searched far and wide, and it seems that, for whatever reason, you cannot assign an action to <kbd>space</kbd> on its own. Assigning it to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> works just fine:

```json
{ "keys": ["alt+space"], "command" : "center_on_cursor", 
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}] }
```

as does assigning it to a function key (<kbd>F7</kbd>, for example), or even to a single letter, like <kbd>M</kbd>. However, `space` on its own only results in the cursor moving one character forward when in command mode. The good news is that hitting <kbd>z</kbd>,<kbd>z</kbd> (lowercase) whilst in command mode will do what you originally wanted to do, which is center the cursor (as does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, as you indicated). Unfortunately, it is **not** possible to remap this action onto the spacebar on its own. The programmed action of space in command mode,

```
set_motion {"clip_to_line": true, "motion": "vi_move_by_characters", "motion_args": {"extend": true, "forward": true, "visual": false}}
```

just seems to be hard-programmed in. Sorry.

Comment: It didn't work (for me). The keyboard shortcut `ctrl-l` does the very thing I'd like the space bar to.

Comment: this is a very interesting problem. Don't worry, I'm still working on it, I just can't figure out why `space` can't be reassigned...

Comment: Thanks for your sleuthing. I'll work around the limitation. (There's more than enough in Sublime to make up for it.)

Comment: @muffinmad did that work for you, or are you just suggesting to try it? Because the spacebar's name is `space`, as I described in my answer. `" "` is not a bindable key name.

Comment: @MattDMo It works for me. But I'm using sublime text 3.
`{"keys": [" ", "w"], "command": "save", "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}]}`

Comment: @muffinmad I mentioned this in my answer - it's possible to bind a command to a key combination that *includes* space, but not to space alone, as the OP is asking.

Comment: @MattDMo Just tested this: `{"keys": [" "], "command": "enter_insert_mode", "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}]}`. Works fine.